# change server from apache to Nginx

Tags: nginx, webserver, centos7

We used to use a  apache web server and for rewriting we used htaccess. Now we changed the web server to Nginx. So my question is which file should I use for re-writing URL? How can I rewrite URL by Nginx? (Which file?  And how?) 
Look forward to hearing from you soon
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx doesn't have support for htaccess files. You should create all rewrite rules in file with domain config. [Here](https://winginx.com/en/htaccess) You have simple htaccess -> nginx rules converter. Hope it helps.

But if You don't know how to use nginx, and why You change webserver, just stay on apache :)